# Maatweb/Excel data reading error (Laravel)

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I am reading a excel sheet in  to laravel using Maatweb plugin.
It works fine when I read from normal excel file.But when I use a protected excel(READ ONLY) it does not work like earlier.
This is the code

```
Excel::load($file, function($reader) { 
$results = $reader->all();
if($results){
             dd($results);
            }
        });
```

In both occasions
$results variable have the row collection but when I access it by using

```
 foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
  echo $key->Name;
}
```

It displays nothing with protected excel.It works fine with the normal file
Here are the images of excel files

*Excel where it works[image: Normal working]
*Excel where it does not work [image: Error]

Can any one explain why is this  working  on the 1st instance and why not in the second??

Comment: you probably have to change permissions on protected excel

Comment: This excel is generated from a finger print machine.I can edit for now.But is there any thing I can do other than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protected sheet loading is not supported by Maatweb/Excel.
Only option is to edit the permission.But in my case I cant use that because I am using a file created by another software.So if you are in the same problem try editing the permission.Thumbs up!!!!!